# How to Display and hide an image in ListField on click in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i am working with ListFields. i  need to customize the ListField.  i have this picture (
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/custom-list-field/td-p/2618419 ) :

[image]

i get the list of installed apps with `CodeModuleManager` and now i want to show that in the ListField as you can see in the above picture.  you can see the lock pic in black, i need to customize that pic on click.

i mean when i click any Row i want to remove that Lock pic in black from that clicked row in the list filed and when i click again to that same row i want to insert that Lock pic back into that row.

I think i have to call the `drawListRow()` method in the on click or something else?  when i click on the list, lock image in the black should disappear. when i again click on the list it should appear again.

here is the Screen code i have used:

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    CustomListField myListView;

    public MyScreen() {

        Bitmap listThumb = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");
        String listTitle="Headline";
        String listDesc = "Mobile news feeds";
        String listDesc2 = " ";
        final Bitmap navBar = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("lock.png");
        Vector v = new Vector();
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
            v.addElement(new ListRander(listThumb, listTitle, listDesc,listDesc2, navBar));
        }
        //v.addElement(new ListRander(listThumb, listTitle, listDesc,listDesc2, navBar));

        myListView = new CustomListField(v){


            protected boolean trackwheelClick (int status, int time) {

                Dialog.alert(" You have selected :" + getSelectedIndex());

                return super.trackwheelClick(status, time);
            }
        }
        ;
        add(myListView);   


    }
}
```

Row data class:

```java
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;

public class ListRander {

    private Bitmap listThumb= null;
    private Bitmap navBar = null;
    private String listTitle=null;
    private String listDesc= null;
    private String listDesc2= null;

    public ListRander(Bitmap listThumb,String listTitle, String listDesc, String listDesc2, Bitmap navBar) {
        this.listDesc = listDesc;
        this.listDesc2 = listDesc2;
        this.listThumb = listThumb;
        this.listTitle = listTitle;
        this.navBar = navBar;
    }
    public Bitmap getListThumb() {
        return listThumb;
    }
    public void setListThumb(Bitmap listThumb) {
        this.listThumb = listThumb;
    }
    public Bitmap getNavBar() {
        return navBar;
    }
    public void setNavBar(Bitmap navBar) {
        this.navBar = navBar;
    }
    public String getListTitle() {
        return listTitle;
    }
    public void setListTitle(String listTitle) {
        this.listTitle = listTitle;
    }
    public String getListDesc() {
        return listDesc;
    }
    public void setListDesc(String listDesc) {
        this.listDesc = listDesc;
    }
    public String getListDesc2() {
        return listDesc2;
    }
    public void setListDesc2(String listDesc2) {
        this.listDesc2 = listDesc2;
    }
}
```

Custom List Field:

```java
package mypackage;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYRect;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;

public class CustomListField extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback {

    private Vector _listData;
    private int _MAX_ROW_HEIGHT = 60;
    public CustomListField (Vector data) {

        _listData = data;
        setSize(_listData.size());
        setSearchable(true);
        setCallback(this);
        setRowHeight(_MAX_ROW_HEIGHT);

    }

    protected void drawFocus (Graphics graphics, boolean on) {

        XYRect rect = new XYRect();
        graphics.setGlobalAlpha(150);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        getFocusRect(rect);
        drawHighlightRegion(graphics,HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS,true,rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);

    }

    public int moveFocus (int amount, int status, int time) {

        this.invalidate(this.getSelectedIndex());
        return super.moveFocus(amount, status, time);

    }

    public void onFocus (int direction) {

        super.onFocus(direction);

    }

    protected void onUnFocus () {

        this.invalidate(this.getSelectedIndex());

    }

    public void refresh () {

        this.getManager().invalidate();

    }

    public void drawListRow (ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int w) {

        ListRander listRander = (ListRander)_listData.elementAt(index);
        graphics.setGlobalAlpha(255);
        graphics.setFont(Font.getDefault().getFontFamily().getFont(Font.PLAIN, 24));
        final int margin =5;
        final Bitmap thumb= listRander.getListThumb();
        final String listHeading = listRander.getListTitle();
        final String listDesc= listRander.getListDesc();
        final String listDesc2= listRander.getListDesc2();
        final Bitmap nevBar = listRander.getNavBar();
        //list border
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawRect(0, y, w, _MAX_ROW_HEIGHT);

        //thumbnail border & thumbnail image
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(margin-2, y+margin-2,thumb.getWidth()+2, thumb.getHeight()+2, 5, 5);
        graphics.drawBitmap(margin, y+margin, thumb.getWidth(), thumb.getHeight(), thumb, 0, 0);

        //drawing texts
       // graphics.setFont(FontGroup.fontBold);
        graphics.drawText(listHeading, 2*margin+thumb.getWidth(), y+margin);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // graphics.setFont(FontGroup.smallFont);
        graphics.drawText(listDesc, 2*margin+thumb.getWidth(), y+ margin+20);
        graphics.drawText(listDesc2, 2*margin+thumb.getWidth(), y+ margin+32);

        //draw navigation button
        final int navBarPosY = y+(_MAX_ROW_HEIGHT/2 - nevBar.getHeight()/2);
        final int navBarPosX = Graphics.getScreenWidth()- nevBar.getWidth()+ margin;
        graphics.drawBitmap(navBarPosX-10, navBarPosY, nevBar.getWidth(), nevBar.getHeight(), nevBar, 0 , 0);

    }

    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {

        String rowString = (String) _listData.elementAt(index);
        return rowString;

    }

    public int indexOfList (ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {

        for (Enumeration e = _listData.elements(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {

            String rowString = (String) e.nextElement();
            if (rowString.startsWith(prefix)) {

                return _listData.indexOf(rowString);

            }

        }

        return 0;

    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {

        return 3 * listField.getRowHeight();

    }

}
```

Comment: when i click on the list, lock image in the black should disappear. when i again click on the list it should appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to follow your code, because your variables are not named properly (e.g. lock.png used by `navBar`).  Please try to clean that up a little in the future ... you'll be able to get better answers that way.

From your code, I can see that the lock image is drawn in `drawListRow()` with this code:

```
    final int navBarPosY = y+(_MAX_ROW_HEIGHT/2 - nevBar.getHeight()/2);
    final int navBarPosX = Graphics.getScreenWidth()- nevBar.getWidth()+ margin;
    graphics.drawBitmap(navBarPosX-10, navBarPosY, nevBar.getWidth(), nevBar.getHeight(), nevBar, 0 , 0);
```

So, you simply need to keep track of a boolean for each row that `drawListRow()` can check to decide if the lock should be drawn or not.   Add a new *locked* property to `ListRander`, which represents one row:

```
public class ListRander {
   private boolean locked = true;  // defaults to "locked"
   public boolean isLocked() {
      return locked;
   }
   public void setLocked(boolean value) {
      locked = value;
   }
```

then, you would change your click handler code to this:

```
  myListView = new CustomListField(v){

     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        int index = getSelectedIndex();
        ListRander lr = (ListRander) get(this, index);
        lr.setLocked(!lr.isLocked());
        // force a repaint of this row
        invalidate(index);
        return true;   // event consumed
     }

     //protected boolean trackwheelClick (int status, int time) {
     //  keep this commented out, unless trackwheel devices need special logic
     //}
  };
```

This will require changing your `CustomListField#get(ListField, int)` method, which would normally return the full data object for a row:

```
  public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
     return _listData.elementAt(index);
  }
```

Finally, change `drawListRow()` to use this new boolean value:

```
     if (listRander.isLocked()) {
        // draw lock button
        final int navBarPosY = y+(_MAX_ROW_HEIGHT/2 - nevBar.getHeight()/2);
        final int navBarPosX = Display.getWidth() - nevBar.getWidth()+ margin;         
        graphics.drawBitmap(navBarPosX-10, navBarPosY, nevBar.getWidth(), nevBar.getHeight(), nevBar, 0 , 0);
     }
```

Comment: hi , i have change my code as you suggested above but it is not working. when i click the row to disappear the lock icon nothing happened. my requirement is when i click on particular row in the list filed, lock image in the black should disappear. when i again click on same row in the list it should appear again.

Comment: @user12345, sorry, there was a cut and paste error in my code, in the `navigationClick()` method.  I've fixed it above.  Please copy the new `navigationClick()` code and try again.  I did test this code in my app, and it works fine.  But, I had to paste small snippets into my answer, and I missed a piece :(